# Keycloak reset-password form prefill username

Tags: keycloak

In keycloak web console it's possible to reset password with url like 
https://server.url/auth/realms/master/login-actions/reset-credentials. But user always needs to fill the email. When I'm redirecting to this page from another application I already know the email so I'd like to pre-fill it. Is it somehow possible?
I've tried to add parameter `?username=some@email.com` but that isn't working, username/email field is still empty.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this question too. Did you find a solution ?